# Use D class from C code

Tags: c, class, bison, d

So, this is what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Let's say we have this :

```
class someClass
{
     string someVar;

     this(string v)
     {
          someVar=v;
     }

     void print()
     {
          writeln(someVar);
     }
}
```

In D, we could do something like :

```
someClass cl = new someClass("value");
cl.print();
```

How could we use `someClass` in C code?

---

**P.S.** *If you're wondering what I'm trying to do.... I'm currently writing an interpreter in D, using Flex/Bison, so I need a way to interface my D object in the Bison parsing code...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SomeClass
{
     string someVar;

     this(string v)
     {
          someVar=v;
     }

     void print()
     {
          writeln(someVar);
     }
}

extern(C) void* newSomeClass(char *v) {
    return cast(void*)(new SomeClass(to!string(v))); // \0 terminated
}

extern(C) void SomeClass_print(SomeClass cls) {
    cls.print();
}
```

I think you get the idea, you have to make an `extern(C)` function for every method of your class. You might be able to automatically generate that code though (pretty straight forward).
There are a few more problems GC related, but nothing you can't deal with, but it's kind of a pain.

Comment: Well, THAT looks interesting. Let me play a bit with the idea and I'll let you know how it goes... ;-)

Comment: Hmmm... tried something along these lines but DMD seems to be complaining : `cannot implicitly convert expression (new SomeClass) of type someClass.SomeClass to void*`...

Comment: Yeah, forgot that you need to cast to void* explicitly (I update the post).

Comment: Aye, another D user and I are actually working on automating this whole thing with SWIG, so the D side generates its extern(C) code, a .h file, and a SWIG interface file, which can then be used to autogenerate a reconstruction of the class in other languages. I don't think the code is available yet, the other person has been doing most the work after i started it

Answer (score 4):

You need to write functions in D that work with pointers to opaque types, and export them with C calling conventions. See http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html. You need to watch out for garbage collection and whatnot. It's a pain.

For your purposes I suggest you look at a D-specific parser generator rather than using Bison. They are usually based on compile-time metaprogramming so you don't need a separate build step, which is an added plus.

You can also write the parser in C, output C structures and then translate those C structures to D structures in D. This seems easier as D makes it easy to use C APIs but not vice versa.

Comment: Yes, flex and bison should be avoided in favor of something more modern because (by default) they're heavy users of globals.

Comment: Well, I'm currently looking into it. As for Bison-alternatives (for D), I think you got a point there, but it happens I'm a bit too familiar with Bison to let it go that easily. :-) Also, have in mind that my parser's requirements are rather complex so using a not-that-mature version of parser work-in-progress would not be ideal...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I added an extra option to the answer in case you insist on using C-based tools.